# Can i transfer token contract on sepolia testnet to Safe smart contract wallet address on bnb smart chain?

Tags: multisignature, binance-smart-chain

I want to use safe smart contract wallet address as multi-sig wallet for our token smart contract to mint/send & transfer tokens. Before connecting to our actual token smart contract we want to test the contract which is currently deployed to sepolia testnet, Will this work for our newly created safe smart contract wallet on binance smart chain ?

Regards

Comment: Normal bridges won't support transferring tokens between a test and a production network. You can run your own bridge it doesn't make much sense except for testing purposes.